# Comparison of two data frames and getting the differences by two columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare two data frames, for example

```
import pandas as pd

az_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['CR1', 'CR2'], 'age': [1, 5], 'dr':[1, 2]})[['name', 'age']]
za_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['CR2', 'CR1'], 'age': [2, 1], 'dr':[2, 4]})[['name', 'age']]
```

AZ_DF table:

| name | age | dr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CR1 | 1 | 1 |
| CR2 | 5 | 2 |

ZA_DF table:

| name | age | dr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CR1 | 1 | 4 |
| CR2 | 2 | 2 |

And I want to get the summary table of different values grouped by 'name' and 'age' columns between az_df and za_df, like:

| name | only in AZ | only in ZA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CR2 | 5 | 2 |

So far, I did merged them,

```
merge = pd.merge(az_df, za_df, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

For az_df, different values are:

```
only_in_az = merge[merge['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

And for za_df:

```
only_in_za = merge[merge['_merge'] == 'right_only']
```

However, I don't know how to build the summary table, I mentioned above, showing the different names' ages for az and za data frames.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

az_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['CR1', 'CR2'], 'age': [1, 5], 'dr':[1, 2]})[['name', 'age']]
za_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['CR2', 'CR1'], 'age': [2, 1], 'dr':[2, 4]})[['name', 'age']]

merge = pd.merge(az_df, za_df, on='name', how='outer')
merge.rename(columns={'age_x': 'only in AZ', 'age_y': 'only in ZA'}, inplace=True)
merge

  name  only in AZ  only in ZA
0  CR1           1           1
1  CR2           5           2
```

If you want to remove duplicates:

```
merge = merge[merge['only in AZ'] != merge['only in ZA']]
merge

  name  only in AZ  only in ZA
1  CR2           5           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want from the merge dataframe using pivot_table:

```
pd.pivot_table(merge.query('_merge != "both"'), values='age', index='name', columns='_merge').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename(columns={'left_only':'only in AZ','right_only':'only in ZA'})

name    only in AZ  only in ZA
0   CR2 5   2
```